# How to query for MySQL database schematic

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

In Sqlite, I can query for tables names and their structure like this:

```
SELECT name, sql 
FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type = 'table' AND Name NOT LIKE '%sqlite%'
```

I want to query for database schematic for MySQL database. Some digging in phpMyAdmin, I end with this:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM SCHEMATA, TABLES 
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = TABLE_SCHEMA AND SCHEMA_NAME ='myDb'
```

Unfortunately, this will only output tables names. Is there any sql query do the some work of:

```
mysqldump -u root myDb --no-data=true --add-drop-table=false > myDb.sql
```

Comment: Off-topic rhetorical question (OTRQ): Isn't it difficult to read queries which are written all on one line?

Comment: not sure how you can join to make this work for all tables, but `DESCRIBE tblname` gives you that information for an individual table

Comment: @bernie Describing my problem is rhetorical!

Comment: @MattBusche I need it as sql query because I am going to embed it in my application.

Comment: Sounds like you can do this in two steps: 1. Get the table-names with a metadata query; 2. loop over those table-names issuing a DESCRIBE statement for each table.

Comment: @bernie My application is going to be written in C language.

Comment: @SIFE C doesn't allow loops?

Comment: @MattBusche It does, except I can't execute `DESCRIBE` as query.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'sqlite_master'
order by table_name, ordinal_position
```

based on the accepted answer from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648420/mysql-get-all-columns-from-all-tables)

Comment: Note that the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables/views are a part of the ISO SQL92 standard.  They should be present on all modern RDBMSs.  Unfortunately, SQLite currently does not implement these standard metadata tables/views.