# Describe all tables in the database in a single statement?

Tags: mysql

Is there any statement that can describe all tables in a database?

Something like this:

```
describe * from myDB;
```

Comment: Maybe, you can combine SHOW TABLES; and DESCRIBE for each table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql get all columns from all tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648420/mysql-get-all-columns-from-all-tables)

Comment: There's no single statement that can do it; both [show columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-columns.html) and [describe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/describe.html) require a table name, so you can either do it every time or query the information schema.

Comment: Related, if it's of interest, I wrote a *Describe All Tables* in [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679580).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL schema describe to Github Wiki?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665946/mysql-schema-describe-to-github-wiki)

Comment: A close vote to point it to, though a brand new question, one that has an answer on it that does exactly what you want. Full Disclaimer: an answer I just wrote up.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There is no statement that `describe` all tables at once. Here's some options:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'db_name';
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION;
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_COMMENT, ORDINAL_POSITION FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema != 'information_schema';
```

Comment: Good solution, but even better as `SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION`. Or what I use to keep things short and sweet: `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_COMMENT, ORDINAL_POSITION FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION`.

Comment: i think what @AlexShaffer says is more approriate because or else the statement gives all the columns which is hard to even refer

Comment: @AlexShaffer's comment should be it's own answer, I think. It's excellent and easy to work with.

Comment: I wanted to see a few more columns from my tables as compared to @alex-shaffer , so I used something more like this `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_DEFAULT, IS_NULLABLE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, COLUMN_KEY, EXTRA, ORDINAL_POSITION FROM information_schema.columns WHERE ( table_schema = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME like 'table_name') ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION;`

Comment: if you're lazy like me just copy `SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema != 'information_schema'` and get all schemas at once

Answer (score 12):

To specify each table explicitly:

```
DESCRIBE table_a; DESCRIBE table_b; DESCRIBE table_c;
```

Comment: This is obviously not ideal for situations where you might have hundreds of tables. Pretty much a non-answer.

Comment: "hack for a small db" is already describing the situation that calls for this solution. Your program should calculate for the prompt size and not ignore it (by assuming certain size of data always). Not all answers are panacea, and in fact, only few are.

Answer (score 10):

I am using linux way. First create a ~/.my.cnf to store the username and password for mysql. Next use the snippet below and run it in the linux terminal.

Generate the tables list and filter the header and awk to generate the column. Then, use the same method to DESC table_name.

```
for i in $(mysql MYDBNAME -e 'SHOW TABLES' \
| grep -v "Tables_in" \
| awk '{print $1}'); do \
    echo "TABLE: $i"; 
    mysql MYDBNAME -e "DESC $i"; \
done
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a variation of @AlexShaffer's excellent comment, modified to mirror what the Mac terminal's mysql monitor outputs when asked to describe a table.

```
USE information_schema;

SELECT TABLE_NAME 'Table', COLUMN_NAME 'Field', COLUMN_TYPE 'Type', IS_NULLABLE 'Null',
  COLUMN_KEY 'Key', COLUMN_DEFAULT 'Default', EXTRA 'Extra'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_db'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: The use of ORDINAL_POSITION in the ORDER BY clause from that version could possibly improve your variation (which is closer in spirit to the output from DESCRIBE tablename).

Answer (score 4):

Please create the bash script like below and it will prompt you for details.

> **LINUX ONLY - BASH SCRIPT** - describe-all-tables.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo ""
read -p 'MySQL db: ' DB
echo ""
read -p 'MySQL user: ' USER
echo ""
read -e -p 'MySQL host: ' -i "localhost" HOSTNAME
echo ""
read -s -p 'MySQL password: ' PASSWORD
echo ""

mysql -N -u${USER} ${DB} -p${PASSWORD} -h ${HOSTNAME} --execute="show tables" | while read table; do mysql -u${USER} -h ${HOSTNAME} ${DB} -p${PASSWORD} -v -t --execute="describe $table"; echo -e "\n"; done
```

> **USAGE** - */bin/sh describe-all-tables.sh*

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -B -N -u root -pPASSWORD -h somehost \
-e "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('describe ', table_name, ';') AS query FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='DATABASE_NAME_HERE' " | \
mysql -B -N -u root -pPASSWORD -h somehost DATABASE_NAME_HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a way to get the results to display in a "table" format as it does when running the command from the mysql prompt, but this should describe all tables formatted vertically.

```
mysql -N -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE_NAME --execute="show tables" \
| while read table; do \
    mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE_NAME --execute="describe $table \G"; \
done
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Mysql not describe all tables in the database. The main reason Database main intention Just decentralize power and take care of metadata, but not index the data.

**Connect to the database:**
mysql [-u username] [-h hostname] database-name

**To list all databases, in the MySQL prompt type:**
show databases

**Then choose the right database:**
use MyDB;

**List all tables in the database:**
show tables;

**Describe a table:**
desc table-name **or** 
describe table-name

Comment: perfect answer for drilling down into the structure!