# search for a column name inside the whole database

Tags: mysql, sql

how to search the whole database for a column name in sqli.

Suppose we have 160 tables with many columns i want to look for animals column inside the database. how would i do that. I have seen couple of examples here mostly they search the column name if the table name is known. but what if i dont know the table itself..??

```
table 1, table 2..... table 160 and i am looking for "animal" column in the whole database.
```

i tried if the table is known its working

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME='animal'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648420/get-all-columns-from-all-mysql-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Query

```
SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name='animal';
```

*[Read about INFORMATION_SCHEMA here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html)*

Answer (score 0):

JDBC has a vendor independant solution: [DatabaseMetaData.getColumns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

```
public static void processColumn(Connection con, String column) throws SQLException {
    DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();
    String catalog = null;
    String schema = null;
    String table = null;
    String columnPattern = column;
    try (ResultSet rs = metadata.getColumns(catalog, schema, table, columnPattern)) {
        System.out.printf("Table %s%n", rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
    }
}
```

`null` serves as wildcard.