# In MySQL how to get the subset of a table ,having only those columns which are of numeric type?

Tags: mysql

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM country ;
```

Shows information about all the columns in country and its dataTypes.

But following command gives error

```
SELECT* COLUMNS FROM country where TYPE = INT;
```

**Error:-
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMNS FROM country where TYPE= INT' at line 1 */**

What is the right way to do it ?

Comment: Inventing new syntax and hoping it works is rarely useful. In any case, this can't be done with non-dynamic SQL. This is because the SQL Data Query Language (eg. `SELECT`) *requires* a fixed query shape. Now, if you could take the output of `SHOW COLUMNS ..` (or a query against another metadata table) and use it as a resultset..

Comment: It will probably be more useful to start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648420/get-all-columns-from-all-mysql-tables (a `SELECT` against an information schema metadata table). However, the result still can't be used to replace replace a '*'-with-restrictions in non-dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The first command

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM country ;
```

work  mysql data dictionary  .. so you can see the structure of the table (name and type )

the second work on real table

```
select * COLUMNS FROM country where TYPE= INT;
```

and probably you  don't have created in your table  a column with name TYPE ..

You should use for obtain the column  with the INT type

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_name = 'country' 
and DATA_TYPE = 'INT'
```

Comment: I am getting this error select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_name = 'country' 
and type = 'INT';
/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'type' in 'where clause' */

Comment: Again the error is coming /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_name = 'country' 
and DA' at line 5 */

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the COLUMN Names. You must change the SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME. The result is ordert by the position in table

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'YourSchema'
AND 
  `TABLE_NAME` = 'table1'
AND
  `DATA_TYPE`  IN ('INT')
ORDER BY
  `ORDINAL_POSITION`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax. Try this

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM country WHERE Type = 'int';
```

Carefully put single quote in **data type**

It will show you the columns with datatype `int`.
Now use these columns in select statment.

`SELECT [columns with int dataTye] FROM country`

Comment: But its not printing the subset of the table having only numeric columns and corresponding rows ??

Comment: Watch the answer again.