# populate dropdown menu on SQL columns

Tags: php, html, sql

i have been trying to populate a dropdown menu with the columns of a `SQL` table, but i am stuck. Or all the fields in the dropdown menu are : Array, or the dropdown menu is populated with empty values.

am i missing something?

i tried this code.

`SHOW COLUMNS, DESCRIBE 'TABLE' AND SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE = ikbb;`

```
    <?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'heijsdb_user', 'maus', 'heijsdb') 
    or die ('Cannot connect to db');
    $result = $conn->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ikbb FROM heijsdb");
    echo "selecteer een input om aan te passen";
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='id'>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                $rows[0] = $row;
                  echo '<option value="'.$row.'">'.$row.'</option>';

}

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
?>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIJSD.png)
[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KedMp.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all columns from all MySQL tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648420/get-all-columns-from-all-mysql-tables)

Comment: `$row` is an array.

Comment: value like $row[0] or $row[value] to set option value

Comment: how is this a duplicate since i want to populate a dropdown menu

Comment: I agree Maurice, that duplicate link is bad.

Comment: `echo '<option value="'.$row.'">'.$row.'</option>';` should be something like `echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</option>';` since $row is an array

Comment: @ADyson no result, only empty values

Comment: what does `SHOW COLUMNS FROM ikbb FROM heijsdb` actually return?

Comment: BTW `echo "selecteer een input om aan te passen";
    echo "<html>";` this makes an invalid HTML document. `<html>` should enclose everything else on the page (unless you have a !DOCTYPE directive above that, which you should really). the echo'd text should be inside the body tag

Comment: it's results in showing every column in the table, and the file is a PHP while, so what is the problem?

Comment: @mickmackusa Ok i understood i will take care of it..

Comment: why is everyone on this site so salty. This site is here to learn right?

Comment: Honestly, Maurice, have you tried very hard to debug and self-solve this?  I don't see any error checking beyond the connection and you haven't provided any database data in the question.  I am being fair here.

Comment: I've been stuck at this for 4 hours now..  i can include the database data, but this should work for every database anyway right? It would just be great if someone had an answer for this one.

Comment: @MauricedeVries Could you please show us what this script returns?

Comment: @hexadect added results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to populate a dropdown with an array, and this is why you see `Array` in your select input. Furthermore, you shouldn't add the `html` tag later than `echo` something.

I would recommend this query for getting the columns of a table :

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='your_database' AND `TABLE_NAME`='your_table'
```

To populate a dropdown with these names, simply use this script :

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("server", "user", "password", "database");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='your_database' AND `TABLE_NAME`='your_table'");
echo '<html>';
echo '<body>';
echo '<select name="id">';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['COLUMN_NAME'].'">'.$row['COLUMN_NAME'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
?>
```